# how to get emails using imap xoauth

Tags: java, oauth, imap

How can I retrieve mails from gmail by authenticate imap using xoauth. I have tried the code which have given on Gmail data api for xoauthAuthenticator.java, xoauthprotocol.java,
xoauthsaslclient.java and xoauthsaslclienfactory.java

but i got error like this

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Remote host closed connection during handshake;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:479)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at XoauthAuthenticator.connectToImap(XoauthAuthenticator.java:80)
    at XoauthAuthenticator.main(XoauthAuthenticator.java:114)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:97)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.read0(ResponseInputStream.java:81)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.readResponse(ResponseInputStream.java:67)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Response.<init>(Response.java:83)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.<init>(IMAPResponse.java:48)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.readResponse(IMAPResponse.java:122)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:230)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:91)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:87)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:446)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 19 more
```

What could be reason of it?

Answer (score 0):

SSLHandshakeException is thrown when your SSLhandler doesn't trust the certificate from the host server. You need to add the server's SSL Certificate to your keystore. [Here is a good walk through of the problem](http://www.webapper.com/blog/index.php/2007/02/09/troubleshooting-javaxnetsslsslhandshakeexception/) and how to fix it.